# Deleting from sql database. based on time stamp (cron job)?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cron

I currently have my database updating the timestamp when new records are inserted. It formats like this:

> `2017-08-24 15:48:30.189182`

My question is: how do I delete records that are over, suppose, 3 days old?

I'm assuming I can run a cron job nightly to remove the records older than 3 days. Can someone give me the format for it? I'm not sure how to work with the timestamp data.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: You are expected to **try to write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527).

Comment: if ((time() - strtotime('2017-08-24 15:48:30.189182') > 259200){ //3 days have passed; }

Comment: Thank you!!!!!! And normally I include code. wasn't sure how it needed to be formatted.

Comment: You need to add some code you've been working on so that we can help you. Asking for free code on Stack Overflow is not good practice. To format code, simply add 4 spaces before every line, and leave a blank line before your text.

Answer (score 0):

different database has different way to compute time difference between two days...

MySQL: DATEDIFF(date1,date2);
Oracle: select date1 - date2 from dual;
and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the column is of type `DATE`, you can run a query that deletes all columns where the difference between today and your column is greater than 3.

Replace `table` with your table, and `date_column` with your column-name. Again, this assumes that you've got columns that is of the `DATE`-type, and not a `VARCHAR` or something.

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), date_column) > 3
```

- [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f5f21/1)
- [MySQL Date functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)